# Excel VBA still prompts for password even after coded the password

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

This is an example of my code.

```
Set book = app.Workbooks.Open(wb.Path + "/" + Excel_Name, , , , "r@w51mt35t")
```

Although I have stated the password to open the password protected excel file, it stills prompt me to input the password for that protected excel file.

Just to be clear, I am trying to open another excel file from a macro of a currently active workbook. I have searched through internet and seems like no one had the same problem as me.

Note: The password protected excel file was created by me as well using the following code below.

```
wb.SaveAs wb.path & "\" + thirdtitle + "- TestPad", FileFormat:=51, Password:="r@w51mt35t"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think when saving with password protection you set 2 level protection for both opening and changing. If so you need to do the following:

```
Set book = app.Workbooks.Open(wb.Path + "/" + Excel_Name, , , , "r@w51mt35t", "r@w51mt35t")
```

as the next argument is responsible for next level of protection. Of course, check the password if both are set the same.

Comment: That second password parameter for gaining modify access is called WriteResPassword